# Clip/Make difference between line and polygon layers [QGIS]

Tags: qgis, clip, intersect

I need to clip one layer out of another, both are vector layers (one of them i got from vectorizing a raster layer). When i try to clip out "LowNitro" out of "FlandersAgriculture"

[image: LowNitro and FlandersAgriculture]

Intersect doensn't work either. I also checked whether the CRS (layers and project) are the same and they are.

When i checked the geometry of the layers, i had some invalid output out of the agriculture layer.

Is this the problem and how can i solve it then?

Do i just ignore the invalid data in there or is there a possibility to also take it into account?

Im using Qgis 3.10.0.

[image]

error message
[image: error message]

Comment: My 'go to' first step when something like this happens is to use the `Fix Geometries` Processing Tool on both layers first and see if it works then. That tool is magical.

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot!!